# Confusing vector iterators incompatible runtime error

Tags: vector, iterator, incompatibility

So here is the deal.
I have a container class here,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ObjectManager.h"
#include "Game.h"

ObjectManager::ObjectManager()
{
}

ObjectManager::~ObjectManager()
{
   std::for_each(_objects.begin(),_objects.end(),ObjectDeallocator());
   std::for_each(_dynamicObjects.begin(),_dynamicObjects.end(),DynamicObjectDeallocator());
}


void ObjectManager::Add(std::string name, VisibleGameObject *object)
{
    _objects.insert(std::pair<std::string, VisibleGameObject*>(name,object));
}

void ObjectManager::Remove(std::string name)
{
    std::map<std::string, VisibleGameObject*>::iterator results = _objects.find(name);
    if (results != _objects.end())
    {
        delete results->second;
        _objects.erase(results);
    }
}

int ObjectManager::GetObjectCount() const
{
    return _objects.size();
}

VisibleGameObject* ObjectManager::Get(std::string name) const
{
    std::map<std::string, VisibleGameObject*>::const_iterator results = _objects.find(name);
    if (results == _objects.end())
        return NULL;
    return results->second;
}


void ObjectManager::AddDynamic(VisibleGameObject *object)
{
    _dynamicObjects.push_back(object);
}

void ObjectManager::PostRemoveDynamic()
{
        std::vector<VisibleGameObject*>::const_iterator iter = _dynamicObjects.begin();
    while(iter != _dynamicObjects.end())
    {
        if ((*iter)->IsDeleted())
        {
            delete (*iter);
            _dynamicObjects.erase(iter);
        }
    iter++;
    }
}

const std::vector<VisibleGameObject*>& ObjectManager::GetDynamicContainer()
{
    return _dynamicObjects;
}


void ObjectManager::DrawAll(sf::RenderWindow& renderWindow)
{
    std::map<std::string, VisibleGameObject*>::const_iterator itr = _objects.begin();
    while(itr != _objects.end())
    {
        itr->second->Draw(renderWindow);
        itr++;
    }

    std::vector<VisibleGameObject*>::const_iterator iter = _dynamicObjects.begin();
    while(iter != _dynamicObjects.end())
    {
        (*iter)->Draw(renderWindow);
        iter++;
    }
}

void ObjectManager::UpdateAll()
{
    std::map<std::string, VisibleGameObject*>::const_iterator itr = _objects.begin();
    std::vector<VisibleGameObject*>::iterator iter;
    iter = _dynamicObjects.begin();

    float timeDelta = GameEngine::GetWindow().GetFrameTime();

    while(itr != _objects.end())
    {
        itr->second->Update(timeDelta);
        itr++;
    }

    while(iter != _dynamicObjects.end())
    {
        (*iter)->Update(timeDelta);
        iter++;
    }

}
```

and, using breakpoints, I have determined the problem is in this function here,

```
void ObjectManager::UpdateAll()
{
    std::map<std::string, VisibleGameObject*>::const_iterator itr = _objects.begin();
    std::vector<VisibleGameObject*>::iterator iter;
    iter = _dynamicObjects.begin();

    float timeDelta = GameEngine::GetWindow().GetFrameTime();

    while(itr != _objects.end())
    {
        itr->second->Update(timeDelta);
        itr++;
    }

    while(iter != _dynamicObjects.end())
    {
        (*iter)->Update(timeDelta);
        iter++;
    }

}
```

Specifically, this line,

```
    (*iter)->Update(timeDelta);
```

My internet searches haven't yielded the answer, so now I'm asking you what's making this glitch up. Also I'll post the header if anybody needs to see it. Also also, this is a modified class from an online tutorial.

Edit: The error message is from a built-in assert in the vectors class.(Expression: vector iterators incompatible)

Comment: What's the *exact* error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some sleep I figured it out. As a warning to others, the problem came from one of the objects being updated creating a new dynamic object after the iterator was defined, invalidating it. I will edit this woth some code explaining this once I can get to a computer.